# How to measure phonetic voicing during a stop closure?

Tags: phonology, phonetics

[image]concerning Praat. I am not entirely sure on how to measure the voicing during a stop closure. 
I marked the consonant closure duration. (You can see part of the vowel.) However, I cannot see where the voice bar ends. Could you give me a few tips?

thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYp3H.png)

(additional information) The word is *bag*. The vowel is "a" and the yellow highlighted part corresponds with the consonant closure duration. I need to label the voice bar, i.e., the stretch of glottal pulses during the consonant closure.

Comment: What is a "voicing consonant"? Do you mean _voiced_ consonant? What language is this? What is the actual utterance that was recorded? What is the purpose of the text grid labels?

Comment: @musicallinguist I edited my question :)

Comment: I edited it further to make it clearer, in light of your exchange with @user6726 below (let me know if I misconstrued anything). On a separate note, I'd recommend trying to get better quality recordings. The amount of external noise during the closure makes it difficult to see exactly what is going on with the voicing.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're asking when voicing ceases during the closure period of "g" in "bag", where the closure is the selected piece. Since you don't have physiological data on vocal fold vibration, you would estimate it from the acoustic waveform, looking for quasi-periodic variations in the waveform. Notice to the right that the waveform is fairly flat, but not totally flat, because there's usually some noise.

At the left edge of the closure for about 10 msc there is relatively clear voicing. There is still a low-amplitude of peaks and valleys for most of the closure, using the section after the release as your point of reference. If you could compare "bag" and "back", you could more clearly see whether this is present in /k/ as well. If it is, you should disregard that variation as not reflecting "voicing", since /k/ isn't voiced. Otherwise, if you have low amplitude quasi-periodic variation during consonant closure, then I would say that it counts as "voicing" -- unless you've been told otherwise by your instructor. It is difficult to locate the end of that amplitude variation by visual inspection, and does require a measure of background noise. (60 cycle AC noise would persist through the recording and not just be present during production of certain phonemes).

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/oanr8ms09g18gro889m54cgqyk7qp5mw Hello! thank you very much. This is a link another example. I just want to make sure that I understood everything correctly. The closure duration of the consonant is the "yellow" highlighted part. However, here I think it is difficult to determine the cease of the voicing. It is again darker in the left edge but more difficult to tell.

Comment: It would be better to give the wav file and the text grids, since pictures can get a bit blurry.

Comment: how can I send you a pm?

Comment: Just post a wav file on box, like you did with the picture.